# HTML/CSS button link not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a link to another page of my website inside this button I've made using CSS. However, the button already has formatted text in it and the link apparently only works when I use text inside the `<a></a>` tags. Any ideas how I can just make the entire button a clickable link? Here's the offending code:

```
<nav>
<p class="button"><a href="pictures.htm"></a>Pictures of our destinations</p>
<p class="button">Prices for flights, hotels and all in one deals</p>
<p class="button">Today's deals</p>
<p class="button">Contact us!</p> 
<p class="button">Sign up for an account</p>
</nav>
```

As that code stands, the link does not work and there is no clickable area. However, moving the text from the `<p>` tags to the `<a>` tags makes the link work, but my CSS formatting doesn't apply to it then.

Comment: You should get rid of the wrapping `<p>` tag and simply style the `<a>` tag directly. The wrapping tag seems unecessary.

Comment: Please include your relevant CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a href="pictures.htm" class="button">Pictures of our destinations</a>` instead of the first paragraph

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this

```
<a href="pictures.htm" class="button">Pictures of our destinations</a>
```

You need to put content inside `a` tag that is to be clickable

And now style the button

```
.button{    
/*.......

Your button style properties

.........*/        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could style your `<a>` tag directly adding `class="button"` and remove the `<p>` tag.

```
<a class="button" href="pictures.htm">Pictures of our destinations</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `<p>` tag will solve your issue:

```
<a href="pictures.htm" class="button">Pictures of our destinations</a>
```

Use your own CSS class:

```css
.button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```